# Connect two vms via ethernet step by step

Tags: ethernet, vmware

How to connect two linux VMs via ethernet connection?

> I installed on my VMware on my pc two Fedora VMs. I want to connect them via ehternet connection, I want to perform **ping between them**, how to do this step by step?

Here output of `ifconfig` command on VM1:

```
    [root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9943:3557:39d9:f25e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:a3:ea:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25737  bytes 28917500 (27.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7911  bytes 701863 (685.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 45  bytes 4217 (4.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45  bytes 4217 (4.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.211.137
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Here output of `ifconfig` command on VM2:

```
root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.211.137  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.211.255
        inet6 fe80::dc17:d447:a162:c6b9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:4c:57:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 112014  bytes 136116308 (129.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 33494  bytes 2619940 (2.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10282  bytes 918950 (897.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10282  bytes 918950 (897.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And here is the network settings on VM1 and the same on vm2:

[image]

as you can see I get : `connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Upload the image to [imgur](https://imgur.com/upload) and post here the link.

Comment: @harrymc Added.

Comment: The VMs should be accessible if they are on the same VMware network adapter.

Comment: Both are bridged as you can see @harrymc

Comment: I must be missing something. What's the problem in doing a ping when both are on the network?

Comment: Why does VM2 have an IPv4 address and VM1 not? I've never used VMware, but you should check the "Configure Adapters" settings. Can you also check in your router's menu (under DHCP settings most likely) if both VMs were successfully assigned an IPv4 address?

Comment: After I set both VMs to custom `VMnet1` it worked, I succedded to ping between them